# Scrolling to the next element scrolls back to first instead

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a bar on top of my page which scrolls to the next element every time you click the button in the current element.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap">

   <div class="section">

        Click here!

        <button class="nav" type="button">Go!</button>

    </div>

    <div class="section">

        <button class="nav" type="button">Next!</button>

    </div>

    <div class="section">

        <button class="nav" type="button">Done!</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button.nav').click(function() {
    $('#wrap').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().offset().top
    }, 400);
});
```

The problem: Instead of scrolling to the section with *Done!*, it does not scroll at all when I click *Next!*. The button *Go!* scrolls down correctly.

Comment: Sounds like the body of the document isn't tall enough to scroll further. The browser won't scroll such that the bottom of the document is above the bottom of the viewport.

Comment: It should be tall enough. If I use url scrolling by using setting a different id attribute on each section, it does scroll down to the last element as well.

Comment: Good deal, that means that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position` rather than `offset` and add in your current `scrollTop`:

```
$('button.nav').click(function() {
    var w = $("#wrap");
    w.animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().position().top + w.prop("scrollTop")
    }, 400);
});
```

```js
$('button.nav').click(function() {
  var w = $("#wrap");
  w.animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).parent().next().position().top + w.prop("scrollTop")
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.section {
  height: 20em;
}
#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div class="section" id="a">

    Click here!

    <button class="nav" type="button">Go!</button>

  </div>

  <div class="section" id="b">

    <button class="nav" type="button">Next!</button>

  </div>

  <div class="section" id="c">

    <button class="nav" type="button">Done!</button>

  </div>

  <div style="height: 50em"></div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here's a version that wraps back to the top:

```js
$('button.nav').click(function() {
  var w = $("#wrap");
  var next = $(this).parent().next(".section");
  var top = next.length ? next.position().top + w.prop("scrollTop") : 0;
  w.animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 400);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.section {
  height: 20em;
}
#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

  <div class="section" id="a">

    Click here!

    <button class="nav" type="button">Go!</button>

  </div>

  <div class="section" id="b">

    <button class="nav" type="button">Next!</button>

  </div>

  <div class="section" id="c">

    <button class="nav" type="button">Done!</button>

  </div>

  <div style="height: 50em"></div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! :D Though I had to remove `w.prop("scrollTop")` or it would scroll down to the bottom once I had gone past the first scrolling element.

Comment: @Sander: Probably a difference in CSS. :-) Glad that helped!